# How to resolve gl_Layer not accessible in Fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am using gl_Layer for layered rendering and I allot a layer value in geometry shader. However, when I use gl_Layer in Fragment shader I get the error:

gl_Layer is not accessible in this profile

Here is my shader:

```
#version 400 core

uniform sampler2DArray diffuse;
in vec2 outtexcoords;

layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(diffuse, vec3(outtexcoords, gl_Layer));
}
```

I can ofcourse bypass this by using another in/out variable, but I want to know what is the problem in using gl_Layer in fragment shader.
I have tried using "in int gl_Layer" in Fragment program, but I guess that is not the solution because its in an inbuilt variable.

Is it because I am not using the right extension? Or that my GL version doesnt support it yet?

Comment: If you write the shader targeting `#version 430`, then this would be valid. But that is not an input to the fragment shader stage ordinarily in older GLSL versions.

Comment: Yes that is probably it. Its allowed 4.3 onwards.

Answer (score 3):

You specified GLSL 4.0 core profile, but its spec says that `gl_Layer` may be used only in geometry shader, and only as output parameter. Previous GLSL versions allowed it's use in fragment shader as read-only variable.